# Oracle regex to extract string between first pair of < and > brackets

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I am have been assigned a task to parse a string (which is essentially in XML format) and I need to extract the name of the first tag in the string

eg: string `'<column><data-type>string</data-type>.............'`
or    `'<filter><condition>....</condition>...............'`
or

'......................'

the string keeps changing but I am only interested in the first tag, I would like to get the output like:

- column,
- filter,
- query

i have tried `regexp_substr(string,'^<(.+)>',1,1,null,1)` and some similer variations but they don't seem to be working cosistently.

Please help.

Comment: As MT0 says - use XML functions on XML data. For example, your input may have a self-closing tag (whose only purpose is to carry an attribute) - like `<column id="0034"/>`. Presumably you still must retrieve the property name, `column` - not the entire junk between the opening and closing angled bracket.

Comment: @mathguy it is safe to assume that there will not be such singular tags like <column id="0034" />, at least not in the first tag that I am looking for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for *any* character between the bounds -- and that includes `'>'`.  So, just exclude the terminating character:

```
select regexp_substr(string,'^<([^>]+)>',1,1,null,1)
from (select '<column><data-type>string</data-type>.............' as string from dual union all
      select '<filter><condition>....</condition>...............' from dual
     ) x;
```

Comment: This will get also get attributes, if any exist, on the root element.

Answer (score 1):

If you have XML data then use a proper XML parser:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY( '/*/name()' PASSING XMLTYPE(value) RETURNING CONTENT ) AS tag_name
FROM   table_name
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT '<column><data-type>string</data-type></column>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<filter><condition>....</condition></filter>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<query />' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<has_attributes attr1="do not return this" attr2="&lt;or&gt; this" />' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | TAG_NAME       |
> | :------------- |
> | column         |
> | filter         |
> | query          |
> | has_attributes |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aaa461ead877e44d85d276cbd63bd6e8)*

Comment: This is a great solution but somehow the xmltype part is not working on my device, but @Gordon Linoff's regex solution is giving me the needed output as the tags are simple.

so thanks a lot again